# Angular Slickgrid- how to update or replace particular cell value with the option selected in context-menu

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, slickgrid

I'm refereeing this [example](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example7-events.html) of slickgrid for `context-menu`

In the image given below I'm using [angular-slickgrid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-slickgrid) along with [ngx-contextmenu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-contextmenu), where I'm displaying my context menu only when a particular cell is clicked in status column, Based on particular cell value different option has been displayed in `context-menu`.

My problem is when I want to update or replace that particular cell value with the selected option from context menu eg: "Inprogress" should replace or update as "Suspended" from `context-menu`.

[image: Image of angular-slickgrid with ngx-context menu]

> HTML code

```
/**************HTML code********************/    

 /**********angular-slickgrid code************/                                       
<div id="container">
 <angular-slickgrid                                                                     
  gridId="grid" 
 (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event)" 
  gridWidth="'90%'" 
  [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"   
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions" 
  [dataset]="dataset" 
  (onGridStateChanged)="gridStateChanged($event)">
  </angular-slickgrid>
</div>   

/*************ngx-contextmenu code***********/ 

<context-menu #editMenuRight>
  <ng-template *ngFor="let item of mainOption" contextMenuItem>
     <li #myLi class="myLi" data="low" (click)="test1()">{{item?.option}}</li>
  </ng-template>                                                                             
</context-menu>
```

> Angular Component code

```
/*************Angular Component code***********/ 

import { Component, OnInit, Injectable, ViewEncapsulation, HostListener, ViewChild, Input,
ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {
Column, GridOption, AngularGridInstance,
Filters, ExtensionName, FieldType, Formatter, Formatters,
Editors,EditorArgs, EditorValidator, Statistic, GridStateChange,
GridOdataService, OperatorType, OnEventArgs, MultipleSelectOption
} from 'angular-slickgrid';
import { ContextMenuComponent } from 'ngx-contextmenu';
import { ContextMenuService } from 'ngx-contextmenu'; 

@Component({
selector: 'app-schedule',
templateUrl: './schedule.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./schedule.component.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit {

/*******my option which I'm showing for particular cell if cell value matches with option****/
 public mainOption: any[];
 public scheduleOption: any[] = [{
 option: 'Scheduled',
 }, {
 option: 'Suspended',
 },
 {
 option: 'Abort',
 }];
 public suspendedOption: any[] = [{
 option: 'Suspended',
}, {
option: 'Scheduled',
},
{
option: 'Abort',
}];
public inprogressOption: any[] = [{
option: 'Inprogress',
}, {
option: 'Suspended',
},
{
option: 'Abort',
}];
public abortOption: any[] = [
{
option: 'Abort',
}];
public completeOption: any[] = [
{
  option: 'Completed',
}];
@ViewChild('editMenuRight') public editMenuRight: ContextMenuComponent;
@ViewChild("myLi") divView: ElementRef;
@Input() contextMenu: ContextMenuComponent;

constructor(private http: Http,
private httpClient: HttpClient,
private elementRef:ElementRef,
private remoteservercommunicationservice: RemoteServerCommunicationService,
public pathstorageservice: PathStorageService,
private globaldataservice: GlobalDataService,
private contextMenuService: ContextMenuService)
);

angularGridReady(angularGrid: AngularGridInstance) {
this.angularGrid = angularGrid;
this.gridObj = angularGrid && angularGrid.slickGrid || {};
 }

/********* display context-menu code******/
public onContextMenu($event, item: any): void {
console.log(item);
console.log($event);
setTimeout(() => {
this.contextMenuService.show.next({
contextMenu: this.contextMenu,
  event: $event,
  item: item,
});
$event.preventDefault();
$event.stopPropagation();
});
}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.columnDefinitions = [
  {
    id: 'Status',
    name: 'Status',
    field: 'Status',
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    onCellClick: (e, args) => {
      let v = args.dataContext.Status;
      var cell = this.angularGrid.slickGrid.getCellFromEvent(e);
      var msg = this.angularGrid.slickGrid.getColumns()[cell.cell].id;
      console.log(cell);
      console.log(msg);
      /******** replacing option based on cell value******/
       if (v == "Scheduled")
      {
        this.mainOption = this.scheduleOption; /***** replacing option here******/
        this.onContextMenu(e,'right'); /***opening context-menu on cell click if its true***/ 
        return  this.mainOption;
      }
      if (v == "Inprogress")
      {
        this.mainOption = this.inprogressOption;
        this.onContextMenu(e,'right');
        return  this.mainOption;
      }
      if (v == "Completed")
      {
        this.mainOption = this.completeOption;
        this.onContextMenu(e,'right');
        return  this.mainOption;
      }
      if (v == "Abort")
      {
        this.mainOption = this.abortOption;
        this.onContextMenu(e,'right');
        return  this.mainOption;
      }
      if (v == "Suspended")
      {
        this.mainOption = this.suspendedOption;
        this.onContextMenu(e,'right');
        return  this.mainOption;
      }
     return  this.mainOption;
     }
   }
  ]
 }
   /*** my problem is here, I want to fetch particular <li> tag value and replace or update the 
        particular cell with that fetch value after click in context menu or with particular option 
        selected in menu***********/   

 ngAfterViewInit() {
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#editMenuRight").click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is("li")) {
      return;
    }
    if (! this.gridObj.getEditorLock().commitCurrentEdit()) {
      return;
    }
    var row = $(this).data("row");
    this.dataset[row].Status = $(e.target).attr("data");
    this.gridObj.updateRow(row);
   });
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure out to update the cell using ngx-context menu below is the gif image of my solution hope it may help someone.

[Slickgrid with ngx-context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX3Xs.gif)

> Html code

```
/********************HTML code*******************/
<context-menu #editMenuRight>
 <ng-template (execute)="gridUpdate()" *ngFor="let item of mainOption" contextMenuItem>
    <ul id="contextMenu">
        <li #myLi class="myLi" data="Low">
            <img src="assets\images\statusMenu\{{item?.src}}" style="width:20px; 
             height:15px; display: inline-block;" class="image">
            <div>
                {{item?.option}}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </ng-template>
</context-menu>
```

> Component-code

```
/*********Component code***********/
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable, ViewEncapsulation, HostListener, ViewChild, 
Input,
ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {
Column, GridOption, AngularGridInstance,
Filters, ExtensionName, FieldType, Formatter, Formatters,
Editors,EditorArgs, EditorValidator, Statistic, GridStateChange,
GridOdataService, OperatorType, OnEventArgs, MultipleSelectOption
} from 'angular-slickgrid';
import { ContextMenuComponent } from 'ngx-contextmenu';
import { ContextMenuService } from 'ngx-contextmenu'; 

@Component({
selector: 'app-schedule',
templateUrl: './schedule.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./schedule.component.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit {

/***********************context-menu option & src id for image icon ****************/
cellValue: any;
public mainOption: any[];
public scheduleOption: any[] = [{
option: 'Scheduled', src:'schedule.png'
}, {
option: 'Suspended', src:'suspended.png'
},
{
option: 'Abort', src:'abort.png'
}];
public suspendedOption: any[] = [{
option: 'Suspended', src:'suspended.png'
}, {
option: 'Scheduled', src:'schedule.png'
},
{
option: 'Abort',  src:'abort.png'
}];
public inprogressOption: any[] = [{
option: 'Inprogress', src:'inprogress.png'
}, {
option: 'Suspended', src:'suspended.png'
},
{
option: 'Abort', src:'abort.png'
}];
public abortOption: any[] = [
{
option: 'Abort',  src:'abort.png'
}];
public completeOption: any[] = [
{
  option: 'Completed', src:'complete.png'
 }];

/****************************************/

@ViewChild('editMenuRight') public editMenuRight: ContextMenuComponent;
@Input() contextMenu: ContextMenuComponent;

  constructor(private http: Http,
  private httpClient: HttpClient,
  private elementRef:ElementRef,
  private remoteservercommunicationservice: RemoteServerCommunicationService,
  public pathstorageservice: PathStorageService,
  private globaldataservice: GlobalDataService,
  private contextMenuService: ContextMenuService)
 );

 angularGridReady(angularGrid: AngularGridInstance) {
 this.angularGrid = angularGrid;
 this.gridObj = angularGrid && angularGrid.slickGrid || {};
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 this.columnDefinitions = [
 {
 id: 'Status',
 name: 'Status',
 field: 'Status',
 sortable: true,
 filterable: true,
 onCellClick: (e, args) => {
  let v = args.dataContext.Status;
      console.log(v);
      var cell = this.angularGrid.slickGrid.getCellFromEvent(e);
      this.cellValue = cell.row;        // to get particular cell row number on click
      var msg = this.angularGrid.slickGrid.getColumns()[cell.cell].id;
      console.log(cell);
      console.log(msg);

  /******** replacing option based on cell value******/
   if (v == "Scheduled")
  {
    this.mainOption = this.scheduleOption; /***** replacing option here******/
    this.onContextMenu(e,'right'); /***opening context-menu on cell click if its 
    true***/ 
    return  this.mainOption;
  }
  if (v == "Inprogress")
  {
    this.mainOption = this.inprogressOption;
    this.onContextMenu(e,'right');
    return  this.mainOption;
  }
  if (v == "Completed")
  {
    this.mainOption = this.completeOption;
    this.onContextMenu(e,'right');
    return  this.mainOption;
  }
  if (v == "Abort")
  {
    this.mainOption = this.abortOption;
    this.onContextMenu(e,'right');
    return  this.mainOption;
  }
  if (v == "Suspended")
  {
    this.mainOption = this.suspendedOption;
    this.onContextMenu(e,'right');
    return  this.mainOption;
  }
 return  this.mainOption;
    }
   }
 ]
}
  /**********context menu open code*************/
 public onContextMenu($event, item: any): void {
 console.log(item);
 console.log($event);
 setTimeout(() => {
 this.contextMenuService.show.next({
  contextMenu: this.contextMenu,
  event: $event,
  item: item,
 });
$event.preventDefault();
$event.stopPropagation();
});
}
/******************************************/

/****************************event to fetch selected option of context menu */
fetchValue(event){
 let check1 = event.target.innerText;
 this.check2 = check1;
  console.log(check1);
  console.log(event.target.innerText);
  }
 /***********************************************************/

 /**********************event to update the grid with selected value from context- 
  menu*******/
 gridUpdate(){
 this.fetchValue(event);
 console.log(this.cellValue);
 const updatedItem = 
 this.angularGrid.gridService.getDataItemByRowNumber(this.cellValue);
 updatedItem.Status = this.check2;
 this.angularGrid.gridService.updateItem(updatedItem);

 }

 /**********************************************/
```

> CSS

```
/***************context-menu css*********************/

 #contextMenu {
 font-size: 11px;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 }

 .myLi {
 padding-left: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 }

 .myLi img {
 float: left;
  }
 /********************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

When using angular you shouldn't access the dom directly. There is am output event int ngx-context `execute` which you should relay on. Then you will need to update your `mainOption`.

Here is the link to the documentation:
https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-contextmenu#template

Comment: thanks for letting me know about that and yeah the click operation in context menu can be replace with execute, but my problem is to update the slickgrid cell value with context-menu option